# Map arbitrary hotkey combination to work as multimedia key

Tags: linux, gnome3

I am used to using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> on my laptop keyboard to control volume.

Can I map my desktop keyboard so <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> would emulate a multimedia keyboard's *volume up* button?

Answer (score 0):

The FN-key on notebooks is possibly one of the hardest keys to remap. Nonetheless, it can still be hotkey'ed if it generates a windows event.

See the AutoHotKey documetation on "Special Keys" at the bottom of this page.
 http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys

Which also suggests ways to reconfigure the key's function if it's not a Window's event key.

Also see some user code here:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/282-fn-key-on-a-notebook/

Comment: I don't necessarily want to emulate the combination with FN. I think "multimedia keyboards" these days have dedicated volume keys, that would do it, assuming they are *real* keys. - I am using Linux btw, only used the tags for indication.

Comment: Autokey is an Linux alternative to Windows AutoHotKey but if you don't want that then yes, a multimedia keyboard is the best way to go.